# Android Dagger not building

Tags: android, dagger

I have already added Dagger into my application. Now I am facing the following error after updating Android studio and project updated to the latest AndroidX version.

```
error: [RefersToDaggerCodegen] Don't refer to Dagger's internal or generated code
(see https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/RefersToDaggerCodegen)
```

How to solve this build error.

Edit:
I am trying to inject dagger like the below

```
((App) appContext).getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```

And inside of the interface

```
@SuppressWarnings({"RefersToDaggerCodegen"})
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    ApplicationModule.class,
    DatabaseModule.class,
    NetworkModule.class,
    QuranDataModule.class,
    QuranPageModule.class } )
public interface ApplicationComponent {
     @SuppressWarnings("RefersToDaggerCodegen")
      void inject(QuranDataProvider quranDataProvider);
```

**Edit 2**
I have initialize the component like the following:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("RefersToDaggerCodegen")
  protected ApplicationComponent initializeInjector() {
    return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
        .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
        .build();
  }
```

Still facing the same issue.

Comment: find where you are referring to Dagger's generated code, and if it's intended, then suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("RefersToDaggerCodegen")`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you check my edit. I have added that also but still facing the same issue. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to put the suppression over where you're actually instantiating the component: `DaggerApplicationComponent`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please check my Edit 2

Comment: Maybe `ErrorProne` is just being stupid at this point, does it *really* not specify the file, or the line that it is warning about?

Comment: No nothing else. Just showing error in single line  error: [RefersToDaggerCodegen] Don't refer to Dagger's internal or generated code
(see https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/RefersToDaggerCodegen). Is there any alternative way to solve this?

Comment: Try to configure Error-prone to ignore this warning then

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I fixed the issue. I have updated all the things. I add my solution in answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my project is I am using dagger old version not too old but not latest. So I updated kotlin version and Dagger version to the following

```
kotlinVersion = '1.3.31'
daggerVersion = '2.15'
```

And in your gradle-wrapper.properties please update the distribution url like below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2-all.zip
```

And finally update the errorprone version also

```
classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.8"
```

I have done all the above steps. Now I am able to build my application successfully.

Thanks for the help @EpicPandaForce